# Windows 10 boots slow

Tags: windows-10, boot, asus-laptop

My  ASUS windows 10 laptop boots slows. After displaying manufacturers logo it displays black screen for few minutes which wasn't happing before. This is happing from few days I can't remember what actually caused it.
I tried sfc /scanow to check damages in boot file but it seems to be perfect.
This is not problem from  start up program I have tried disabling them but no improvement.
Can you guys please suggest what might have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware components might be the issue. This might include the HDD/SSD used by your Operating System. Check if your drives are running perfectly with a hard drive health checking tool then replace the failing drive if necessary.